# How can you force expire a salesforce access token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, salesforce, refresh-token

I'm building a web app and using OAuth2 to authenticate. For testing purposes, I would like to test what happens when the access token expires and the refresh token is needed to re-authenticate. Since the salesforce oauth token does not contain an "expiry date" parameter, how would i forcefully expire the salesforce access token.

This is what is returned when a token is requested.

```
{
    "oauth_token": {
        "access_token": "<access token>",
        "id": "https://login.salesforce.com/id/00DG0000000imtwMAA/005G0000001CFgeIAG",
        "id_token": "<id token>",
        "instance_url": "https://na47.salesforce.com",
        "issued_at": "1522400000",
        "refresh_token": "<refresh token>",
        "scope": [
            "refresh_token",
            "full"
        ],
        "signature": "<signature>",
        "token_type": "Bearer"
    }
}
```

Comment: You would get better answers from the folks at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks @Charles that's helpful and good to know for future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do it manually, you can go to **Setup** > **Security Controls** > **Session Management**, then select the session from the list and remove it. Alternatively, if you need to do it programmatically, you could query and delete these records, which are stored in the `AuthSession` object.

Once you've done that, your access token will be expired, and attempts to use it will produce:

> [ {
>     "message" : "Session expired or invalid",
>     "errorCode" : "INVALID_SESSION_ID"
>   } ]

Your refresh token will still be valid though, and you can use it to request a new access token.